# why this warning came ::::::mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php

```
mysql_connect("lacalhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
```

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known.

Comment: its localhost not lacalhost

Answer (score 5):

You spelled `localhost` incorrectly.